# How can I split long string into multiple qr areas?

Tags: java, qr-code

After signing data with RSA key, I have A CMS signature. I need to put that long CMS signature string into qr code. But signature string is too long to generate a single qr. I think I should divide qr into multiple areas(in multiple qrs). Is there a way to divide qr into multiple areas?

Example:

[image]

Recently in Java I tried to use zxing library that can help to generate qr code. But it throws error for long string like any other online services that you can try.

```
String signedData = "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";

QRCodeWriter qrCodeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
BitMatrix bitMatrix = qrCodeWriter.encode(signedData, 
BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 1000, 1000);

File signedFile = new File(id + ".png");

Path path = signedFile.toPath();

MatrixToImageWriter.writeToPath(bitMatrix, "PNG", path);
```

I am expecting to generate multiple qrs from signedData string like in link attachment image in Java.

Comment: I have tested your string with the qrgen generator. A qr code with the matrix of 128x128 and 512x512 did not cause any problems. 
QR codes can contain 4.296 characters. your has much less.

Comment: I'll answer it followed by - https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-scan-more-than-1-QR-code-at-a-time